# PHP Re-submit form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a script that is activated when someone submits a form on that same page. The first time the user fills in data and presses submit, it works, the second time it does not respond.

NOTE: There is a second document where the sessions are created (SESSION_START is given).

```
<?php
      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    
    $_SESSION['aantalpogingen'] = $_SESSION['aantalpogingen'] + 1;
    echo $_SESSION['aantalpogingen'];
    echo "<br />";
    $_SESSION['poging'][$_SESSION['aantalpogingen']] = substr($_SESSION['hetwoord'] , 0 , 1)  . $_POST['PogingLetter2'] . $_POST['PogingLetter3'] . $_POST['PogingLetter4'] . $_POST['PogingLetter5'];
    

echo "<table width='450' height='75' border='1'>";

    foreach($_SESSION['poging'] as $pogingnr=>$gok)
    {
        if($gok != "")
        
        {
            echo "<tr>";
        
        
    
        echo "<th WIDTH='66'>";
        echo $gok[0] ;
        echo "</th>";
        
        echo "<th WIDTH='66'>";
        echo $gok[1] ;
        echo "</th>";
        
        echo "<th WIDTH='66'>";
        echo $gok[2] ;
        echo "</th>";
        
        echo "<th WIDTH='66'>";
        echo $gok[3] ;
        echo "</th>";
        
        echo "<th WIDTH='66'>";
        echo $gok[4] ;
        echo "</th>";
        
        echo "<th>";
        echo "Poging " . $pogingnr;
        echo "</th>";
        
        
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    
    
    echo "  </table";
    

    
}
  ?>
```

I cannot find any syntax errors or anything, I hope you can help me :)

Comment: "the second time it does not respond." what is it's behavior for second time?

Comment: Are you getting any PHP/ console errors? If so please list them.

Comment: None at all , like the button does not submit.

Comment: Did you include `session_start();` anywhere? It's not in your posted code/question. This is required when using `$_SESSION`

Comment: Yes i have that at the top of the page, since the first time the scripts runs successful, but the second time the button does not respond, i also added the html form

Comment: It might have something to do with this line `<input name="Poging1Letter1" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="Poging1Letter1" size="3" maxlength="1" value="<?php echo substr($_SESSION['hetwoord'] , 0 , 1) ;?>`

Comment: I'm curious though, you wrote in your question `SESSION_START` I hope you didn't type that out exactly like that in your code?

Comment: <?php
session_start();
?>  I did edit the PHP script posted here, first it worked, then i changed the script(a lot) and somewhere something went wrong

Comment: You need to do incremental changes, so that when something goes haywire, you'll have a pretty good idea as to what went wrong, and where. Sessions are very tricky, and if you lose track of changes, you can quickly lose focus. I know, it's happened to me and I still have a bit of a hard time with sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found at least one mistake :->

```
echo "  </table";
```

missing `>`

> ```
>   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
> ```
>
> {

This condition meant to be for the not intended below too?

```
echo "<table width='450' height='75' border='1'>";
```

As it's not closed before the `echo`.

Comment: Thank you! , the missing > seemed to be the problem, the other part seems to be OK

Comment: Great, happy that you are :-)